# How do I check if a value is equal to any of two strings?

Tags: rust

I have:

```
if std::env::consts::OS == "macos" {
    // Do something
} else if std::env::consts::OS == "linux" {
    // Do the same thing
}
```

Is there a way I could check for both of these in one line?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the logical "or" operator `||`:

```
if std::env::consts::OS == "macos" || std::env::consts::OS == "linux" {
    // Do something
}
```

Or `match`, which is a tad more terse in expressing what you want to match, but requires you to cover all possibilities, so a catch-all pattern is required even if you don't want to do anything in that case:

```
match std::env::consts::OS {
    "macos" | "linux" => {
        // Do something.
    },
    _ => {
        // No other match arms matched, maybe do something, or don't.
    },
};
```

As a side note, testing what platform you are on is usually a last resort when no other kind of detection will work.  It's better to test what capabilities you have than to ask what platform you are on, for two reasons: first, that's the actual question you want to answer, and second, maybe the platforms that don't have that capability right now will sometime later.

Comment: Another option: `["macos", "linux"].contains(&std::env::consts::OS)`.

Comment: Still another option: `if matches!(std::env::consts::OS, "macos" | "linux") { ... }`